# How do i send grpc request in python?

Tags: python, automation, grpc, http2

I have an azure web app which based on http2 ( grpc ) and has its own url. But still dont know how to send the request there in python for automation things.

Comment: have you read https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/ ?

Comment: do we still need to generate the server code eventho the actual server is on azure?

Comment: No but you need to have|generate the stubs so that you can bind the Python client to these. Before doing that, try using a tool like [`gRPCurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) or [`Postman`](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/) to ensure that you can interact with the gRPC service that's deployed to Azure.

Comment: I use Kreya app which is already working to send the request there. But i just want to tried in python for automation.  
I'm having error in client side which is :
`status = statuscode.unimplemented
details = "Service is unimplemented"`
Perhaps do you know what's the reason?

Comment: This either means that the server has not implemented the method _or_ that the client received an HTTP 404. This second option seems likely. Check your routing logic to make sure that the traffic is actually making it to the gRPC server.

Comment: Thanks, i'm able to solve it. But right now, another problem is that `details = "Request protocol 'HTTP/1.1' is not supported."`. Do you have any idea how to call grpc web from python? Thanks.